# Visualize vector in python

Tags: matplotlib, vector, 3d

I have three vectors and I want to visualize those vectors and angle between them.

```
vector_1 = [0, 0, 1]
vector_2 = [-0.00495  0.11702  0.38329]
vector_3 = [-0.02524  0.03567 -0.03665]
```

I'm computing angle between vector_1 and vector_3, and another angle is vector_2 and vector_3.

I have computed angle between them but how can I visualize that using python matplotlib.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227100/best-way-to-plot-an-angle-between-two-lines-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualize the vectors by drawing lines in 3D space in `matplotlib`. For example, the first line would start from the coordinate `(0,0,0)`, end at `(0,0,1)`

Here is the matplotlib tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.html

Stackoverflow question on how to draw 3D lines: [How can I make a simple 3D line with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541123/how-can-i-make-a-simple-3d-line-with-matplotlib)