# How do I plot a parametrized function in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I plot such function in matplotlib? It a function that returns a point (x,y,z):

```
def f(t):
    return (t, t+4, t)
```

This is supposed to describe a line in 3D space

Splitting them up into three separate component functions is not acceptable for me.

Comment: Is that `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: yeah. I'll elaborate more

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Why would you need  to split this into separate functions?

Comment: The way matplotlib works will requires to split coordinates, but that should not be a problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11541628/3067485

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to split up the function. Just use numpy to create vectors and unpack the result for the plotting.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

def f(t):
    return (t, t+4, t)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":"3d"})
ax.plot(*f(t))
ax.set(xlabel="x", ylabel="y", zlabel="z")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works for now. Do the functions have to be designed to use numpy functions like np.sin or would generic python functions work?

Comment: @MrSomeone It depends on what operations you're doing. But if you want to take the sine of a value, you'll have to use `np.sin` instead of `math.sin`. What other operations do you have in mind?

Comment: No special operations in mind, just wanting to know how arbitrary these functions can be

Comment: @MrSomeone If you do go down this path, read up on numpy. The basics can get you pretty far.